# Element-wise subtraction of dense vectors in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have a Spark Dataframe with two columns that are dense vectors. I want to calculate the element-wise difference of the elements of each vector (for each row of the dataframe).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Even though you can subtract two dense vectors u and v with u-v, you can't subtract two columns of dense vectors with col1-col2.

Therefore I would use a udf:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector, VectorUDT

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([ 
        [DenseVector([1.,1.]), DenseVector([0.,0.])],
        [DenseVector([1.,1.]), DenseVector([1.,0.])],
        [DenseVector([1.,1.]), DenseVector([1.,1.])]
    ], ['u', 'v'])

subtract_vector_udf = F.udf(lambda arr: arr[0]-arr[1], VectorUDT())

df2 = df.select('*', subtract_vector_udf(F.array('u', 'v')).alias('diff'))
df2.show()
>>>
+---------+---------+---------+
|        u|        v|     diff|
+---------+---------+---------+
|[1.0,1.0]|[0.0,0.0]|[1.0,1.0]|
|[1.0,1.0]|[1.0,0.0]|[0.0,1.0]|
|[1.0,1.0]|[1.0,1.0]|[0.0,0.0]|
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Your example works perfect but I'm getting a strange error `AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'array(features_normalized, prediction)' due to data type mismatch: input to function array should all be the same type, but it's [vector, vector];`.. Still both columns are of type `vector (nullable = true)`. Any idea?

Comment: Did you `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`? I edited my post to include it. Maybe they're not the same type of vector: can you do `row = df.select('features_normalized', 'prediction').first()` and look at `type(row[0])` and `type(row[1])` ?

Comment: I had imported `F`. Both types are `pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector`.